How do I dynamically insert a column of data into the middle of a html table which uses both rowspans colspans?
I've got an existing large table that has multiple rowspans and colspans.
Ideally it would be rewritten from scratch to not use one large table, but that isn't an option right now.
By adding classes to the table when it's generated using PHP, I can easily use jQuery to remove an entire column not including the header and footer using, for example:
$(".column3").remove();

I would then like to be able to insert a set of cells to replace the removed cells.  The replaced set of cells will likely have multiple rowspans, but won't have any colspans.
A have a php script that can create a single column in the table.
I'm open to using other libraries.
I would prefer not to recreate every single row/
Example Table
This is an example of the data structure, the actual table is a lot bigger:
https://jsfiddle.net/7xf6ct4b/
<table>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="5">HEADER 1</th>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <th colspan="5">HEADER 1</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="column1">Sub head Left</td>
        <td class="column2">Sub head 1</td>
        <td class="column3">Sub head 2</td>
        <td class="column4">Sub head 3</td>
        <td class="column5">Sub head 4</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="column6">Sub head Left</td>
        <td class="column7">Sub head 1</td>
        <td class="column8">Sub head 2</td>
        <td class="column9">Sub head 3</td>
        <td class="column10">Sub head 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="column1">Left Detail</td>
        <td class="column2" rowspan="4">1st Main Column - Cell 1</td>
        <td class="column3" rowspan="15">2nd Main Column - Cell 1</td>
        <td class="column4" rowspan="6">3rd Main Column - Cell 1</td>
        <td class="column5" rowspan="4">4th Main Column - Cell 1</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="column6">Left Detail</td>
        <td class="column7" rowspan="4">1st Main Column - Cell 1</td>
        <td class="column8" rowspan="15">2nd Main Column - Cell 1</td>
        <td class="column9" rowspan="6">3rd Main Column - Cell 1</td>
        <td class="column10" rowspan="4">4th Main Column - Cell 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="column1">Left Detail</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="column6">Left Detail</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="column1">Left Detail</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="column6">Left Detail</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="column1">Left Detail</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="column6">Left Detail</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="column1">Left Detail</td>
        <td  class="column2" rowspan="4">1st Main Column - Cell 2</td>
        <td  class="column5" rowspan="7">4th Main Column - Cell 2</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="column6">Left Detail</td>
        <td  class="column7" rowspan="4">1st Main Column - Cell 2</td>
        <td  class="column10" rowspan="7">4th Main Column - Cell 2</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="column1">Left Detail</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="column6">Left Detail</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="column1">Left Detail</td>
        <td class="column4" rowspan="6">3rd Main Column - Cell 2</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="column6">Left Detail</td>
        <td class="column9" rowspan="6">3rd Main Column - Cell 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="column1">Left Detail</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="column6">Left Detail</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="column1">Left Detail</td>
        <td  class="column2" rowspan="5">1st Main Column - Cell 3</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="column6">Left Detail</td>
        <td  class="column7" rowspan="5">1st Main Column - Cell 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="column1">Left Detail</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="column6">Left Detail</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="column1">Left Detail</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="column6">Left Detail</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="column1">Left Detail</td>
        <td class="column5"  rowspan="4">4th Main Column - Cell 3</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="column6">Left Detail</td>
        <td class="column10"  rowspan="4">4th Main Column - Cell 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="column1">Left Detail</td>
        <td class="column4"  rowspan="3">3rd Main Column - Cell 3</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="column6">Left Detail</td>
        <td class="column9"  rowspan="3">3rd Main Column - Cell 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="column1">Left Detail</td>
        <td class="column2">1st Main Column - Cell 4</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="column6">Left Detail</td>
        <td class="column7">1st Main Column - Cell 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="column1">Left Detail</td>
        <td class="column2">1st Main Column - Cell 5</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="column6">Left Detail</td>
        <td class="column7">1st Main Column - Cell 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5">FOOTER</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="5">FOOTER</td>
    </tr>
</table>

The best I could find for solutions were of the form:
$('#table > tbody > tr').eq(i-1).after(html)

However thanks to the rowspans, these require you to keep a good track of what's where on the table to understand where in the row a cell should be inserted so it appears in the correct column/
I have looked at datatables, but I'm not clear if that can provide the functionality I want now; a question in the past clarified it couldn't then.

I think there is not a generic way to obtain this.
The jquery remove/detach methods return the objects removed. You can save these object and read for colspan and/or rowspan (if null the value is the default, so 1).
E.g.
var nodes=$(".column3").remove();
nodes.each(function() {
     console.log(this.getAttribute("colspan"), this.getAttribute("rowspan"));
  });

Applying this example to your code return
null, null
null, "15"

